# Not able to launch native Facebook app

Tags: swift, facebook, uiapplication

I´m trying to launch a Facebook page, first I check if it can be opened in the native app and then open in Safari if not. I do have Facebook installed, but it always open the page in Safari. This is the code I´m using.

```
let fbId = "ID" // this is of course a dummy value now
let url = "fb://profile/\(fbId)"
let fbURL = NSURL(string: url)
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(fbURL!){
       UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(fbURL!)              
} 
else {
     //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Facebook
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"http://facebook.com/\(fbId)")!)
}
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS 9, You must whitelist the url's that your app will call out to using the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key in your Info.plist.
So add this code to your plist file:

```
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
 <string>fb</string>
 <string>fbapi</string>
 <string>fbauth2</string>
 <string>fbshareextension</string>
 <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
 <string>twitter</string>
 <string>whatsapp</string>
 <string>wechat</string>
 <string>line</string>
 <string>instagram</string>
 <string>kakaotalk</string>
 <string>mqq</string>
 <string>vk</string>
 <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

You can remove schemes you don't want to use too.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're building for iOS 9.0, you need to update your Info.plist.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:

> IMPORTANT If your app is linked on or after iOS 9.0, you must declare
>   the URL schemes you want to pass to this method. Do this by using the
>   LSApplicationQueriesSchemes array in your Xcode project’s Info.plist
>   file. For each URL scheme you want your app to use with this method,
>   add it as a string in this array.
>
> If your (iOS 9.0 or later) app calls this method using a scheme you
>   have not declared, the method returns NO, whether or not an
>   appropriate app for the scheme is installed on the device.